# How do I get UILabel multiline and auto-shrink to recognise word length?

Tags: swift, uilabel

My issue is trying to get a UILabel to have multiple lines and auto-shrink together at the same time.

Various articles suggest the following approach:

```
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
textLabel.adjustsFontToFitWidth = true
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

This generally works well, except for when a single word is wider than the label, as shown:
[image: Screen shot UILabels]

All labels have fontSize of 17, together with the properties above.  But the third label, which contains the word sesquipedalianism, falls over as a single word is wider than the label frame width.

Anyone know how to get a label to auto shrink for both content and for individual words?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's solves you problem
`textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` change to `.byWordWrapping`

Comment: thanks for the response but unfortunately if you set the ```lineBreakMode``` to ```.byWordWrapping``` then it doesn't autoShrink for those labels where the whole text is too long

Answer (score 0):

Select Your UILable give UILable constants
**THEN**
Auto shrink to Minimum Font Size

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response but sadly the labels are reset regularly with different text and I have no idea of how long it will be.  Reset the ```minimumFontScale``` after I've set the content produces the same result as in my screenshot.

Comment: @GBasher Brother i don't know why you have this issue because If a word is bigger it should shrink its size

Comment: You would think that it should, but unfortunately it doesn't, as can be seen by the third box down in the screen-shot above.

Comment: Yes I'll Study it after Some time and Let you know